# What does it mean by saying "assign unit mass to the whole circle"

Tags: fourier-analysis

From the book i have been reading:
[image: Good kernel]

It seems like i can get somehow the meaning of the expression "assign unit mass to the whole circle" but not exactly enough. Is there any way to think about it more visually? Thanks.

Comment: Do you know what a measure is? (Not essential but it helps.)

Comment: If you are more familiar with classical mechanics, think of a infinitesimally thin ring shaped like the unit circle, with nonuniform mass density given by $K_n(\theta)$.

Comment: @lan i am not sure about what do you want me to get in about "measure". In my experience, i have learnt the measure (in mathematics analysis) like that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics).

Comment: @Rahul indeed, i approach the content in the view of studying math, and i dont know much about classical mechanics, thanks anyway.

Comment: If you know what a measure is, $K_n$ are densities of measures, call them $k_n$, with $k_n(A)=\int_A K_n(x) dx$. Your property (a) is just $k_n([-\pi,\pi])=1$.

Comment: I think that we can consider the integral as a sum. So property (a) says that the mean value when taking the sum  $K_n(x)$ over the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$ is 1, so as you say, $K_n$ are densities of measures. Indeed, i consider $K_n$ is a thing and divide it into densely infinitely many particle - each has a value mean of 1. And the mass of $K_n$ is so equals $1*(2\pi)=2\pi,$ which equals the integral $K_n(x)$ in the interval. Thanks @lan